# How to click a button using HTMLKit when the button is a link?

Tags: swift, htmlkit

I have a button in a code that is like this:

```
<a class"button" type="button" href="#">More</a>
```

This is at the bottom of a page. The page is showing a list of items. When I click it with the mouse, the pages expands and shows more items.

I am using HTMLKit and I want to click that button programmatically.

I am using this

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.innerHTML") {[weak self] result, error in
      guard let html = result as? String, error == nil else { return }
      
      let document = HTMLDocument(string: html)
  
      if let moreButton = document.getElementsByClassName("button")
```

at this point I get `moreButton` and it is an [HTMLElement](https://swiftpackageindex.com/vapor-community/htmlkit/2.8.1/documentation/htmlkit/htmlelement)

If that was a JavaScript element I would do

```
moreButton.click()
```

But in this case, `href` is equal to `#`

How do I click that button programmatically in HTMLKit?

Comment: `<a type="button">` is not valid HTML btw - only `<button type="button">` has that attribute. [The `<a type=""` attribute is for a MIME Content Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement/type).

Comment: Doing `let document = HTMLDocument(string: html)` is re-parsing the HTML outside of the web-browser: so your `let document` variable has zero relationship or connection to the running browser engine in your `webView` - it's just a static DOM-like in-memory object -  so of course it can't "click" anything, it's _inanimate_.

Comment: `<a class"button" type="button" href="#">More</a>` is like it is written on the page. That page is not written by me.  Regarding to your comment 2. What is the solution, then?

Comment: Presumably, just something like `webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.querySelector('a[href].button').click();")` and that's it.

Comment: brilliant. It worked. Please convert this comment into an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not do what I think you think it does:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.innerHTML") {[weak self] result, error in
      guard let html = result as? String, error == nil else { return }
      
      let document = HTMLDocument(string: html)
  
      if let moreButton = document.getElementsByClassName("button")
```

Doing `let document = HTMLDocument(string: html)` in your code is just re-parsing the HTML outside of the web-browser: so your `let document` variable has zero relationship or connection to the running browser engine in your `webView` - it's just a static DOM-like in-memory object - so of course it can't "click" anything, it's inanimate.

But first, a history lesson:

So, ever since the mid-1990s when we could simply *embed* a web-browser / webiew component directly ito our VB/WinForms/etc GUIs, those web-browser components generally exposed a *live DOM API* that their parent programs (i.e. our code) could use to directly access and manipulate the DOM/HTML/document loaded into the web-view - for example, `MSHTML.dll` [exposed the entire HTML+CSS+JS DOM and more](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/ie/mshtml/interfaces/index.htm) [via its `IWebBrowser2` COM interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/mshtml2).

However, since IE's euthanasia and Microsoft's *Invasion of the Body Snatchers*-style replacement of MSHTML/Trident with Chromium, the *live DOM API* has sadly gone too: as of 2024 `IWebBrowser2`'s successor, [*"Microsoft Edge `WebView2`"*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoft-edge/webview2/?form=MA13LH) instead requires consuming applications to *try* to manipulate the loaded HTML+CSS+JS by passing strings of JavaScript and praying that they work. It's as horrible as it sounds, but it's what we have to work with now. And by the looks of things, it seems the same for our cousins in the *Cult of Mac*, c.f. your code interfacing with it via `webView.evaluateJavaScript` which returns result info via an async
callback.

---

Fortunately, what you're asking *can* be trivially accomplished via `evaluateJavaScript` (assuming the DOM tree and loaded HTML behaves predictably and you wait for the `webView` to report the document has fully loaded first *before* using `evaluateJavaScript`). The solution is to just write a script that runs inside the `webView` that gets a DOM reference to that `<a class="button">` and calls its `HTMLAnchorElement.click()` method which *will* cause any `'click'` DOM Event Listener (or `onclick=""` attribute script, if applicable) to be invoked. Like so:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.querySelector('a[href].button').click();") ...
```